# Jconnect 4 jar versions

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, jconnect

I am trying to move from Jconnect 2 to Jconnect 6.
In application i see that there is a jar names jconn2-5.5.
5.5 being Jconnect version.The application is quite old. Now Jconn 4 that i am using has Jconnect version as 16.0. I am not able to find a jar named jconn4-16.0.
My doubt here is, is there a jar named like that or jar was just renamed to 
be specific to the jconnect version? Like jconn2 renamed as jconn2-5.5

Answer (score 2):

The check the actual jconnect version please run:

java -jar jconnX.jar

Jconnect libraries differ in the area of JDBC compliance. Changing the jconnect driver might require also to change the code to use different JDBC library. For example:

- for jconnect version 6 (jconn3.jar)  you would use com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver
- for jconnnect version 7 or 16 (jconn4.jar) you would use com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver

Upgrading the jconnect driver might also require to upgrade Java to a newer version.

- jConnect 5.5 (jconn2.jar) was build using JDK 1.3
- jconnect 6 (jconn3.jar) was build using JDK 1.4
- jConnect 7 or 16 (jconn4.jar) was build using JDK 1.6

Answer (score 0):

The filename of the jConnect driver does not contain the jConnect version number. For example, jconn2.jar => jConnect 5.2 & 5.5; jconn3.jar => jConnect 6.0; jconn4.jar => jConnect 7.0 & 16.0.
In jconn4.jar, you cn get the exact version simply by running 'strings' on the jar file and grepping for 'jConnect'.